# how to fix this IE6 input bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

```
var check = function(){
   return false;
}
var submit = document.createElement("input");
submit.type = "image";
submit.src = "submit1.gif";
submit.onclick = check;
_submitSpan.appendChild(submit);
```

i created a form and append a input button, but i found it can't work in IE6, when click the button, the form auto submitted. can anybody help me.thank you.

Comment: Did you have it wrapped in a <form> element? And if so, what was the 'action' attribute set as? Is it possible for you to set it to action="javascript:;" if it is set to something unnecesary/nothing?

Comment: Why not just `var check = false;`?

Comment: have you tried putting semi colon at the end of function.

Comment: to Danjah: i didn't set the 'action' attribute,i will try it
to Babiker: beacuse there is something else to do before that
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicitly setting the onclick attribute, try binding dynamically to the nodes' `onclick` event instead. Or perhaps you should be looking at the `onsubmit` event of the form.

```
function bindEvent(target, event, handler) {
    if (typeof target.addEventListener != 'undefined') {      
        target.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    } else if (typeof target.attachEvent != 'undefined') {
        target.attachEvent('on' + event, handler); 
    } 
}


function check(e) {
   // Cancel W3 DOM events
   if (typeof e.preventDefault != 'undefined') {
        e.preventDefault();
   }
   // Cancel for old IE event model
   e.returnValue = false;

   return false;
}

var submit = document.createElement("input");
submit.type = "image";
submit.src = "submit1.gif";

_submitSpan.appendChild(submit);

// Bind click event to submit button...
bindEvent(submit, 'click', check);

// ...or perhaps you want to bind submit event to form
bindEvent(submit.form, 'submit', check);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be an idea to hook into a 3rd party lib to handle event inconsistencies et al, YUI does a fine job, as does jquery.

Answer (score 0):

For IE you might have to use the addAttribute method instead of .onclick()

```
submit.addAttribute('onclick', check);
```

Comment: @CunruiLi if(submit.setAttribute) { submit.setAttribute(); } else {submit.onclick = ;}. Differences in browsers mean this is unavoidable

Comment: the setAttribute is defined in all browsers,so the test "submit.setAttribute" may not work. but it would work with just a few modifications. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From [W3C HTML 4.01 Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#input-control-types):

**image**

> Creates a graphical submit button. The value of the src attribute specifies the URI of the >image that will decorate the button. For accessibility reasons, authors should provide >alternate text for the image via the alt attribute.

Do not use an `<input type="image">` like a checkbox. The best way to make an image-checkbox is something like:

```
<label for="input">
<input id="input" style="display:none;" type="checkbox">
<img src="img.gif" alt="Check">
</label>
```

The label will treat the image as a checkbox, and automatically check the hidden checkbox if the image is clicked.